# String list to logical list optimization in R

Tags: r

In .txt are 50000 strings each containing 1024 bit (values 0 or 1) separated by " ". I'm new in R and i get a logical list from one of the 50000 on my own... (loglist)

sample of .txt (two of 50000): sry don't know how to format...
          0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000
0000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010

```
singleString <- paste(readLines("input_7of1024_50k.txt"), collapse=" ")
characterArr <- unlist(strsplit(singleString, split=" ", useBytes="FALSE") )
charList <- strsplit(characterArr, split="", useBytes="FALSE" )
logList <- as.logical(as.numeric(charList[[1]]))
```

I want a list like:

```
[[1]]
    [1] True False False True 
    ....
    [1021] True True False True

[[2]]
    [1] True False False True 
    ....
    [1021] True True False True
```

I searched an hour for my self, i hope i didn't ask twice. Thx a lot.

Comment: 50k rows of strings?

Comment: Can you show a sample of `singleString `

Comment: `lapply(scan("test.txt", what = ''), function(x) as.logical(as.numeric(strsplit(x, '')[[1]])))` works for the example file I used... in which i miscounted and used 2500000 strings

Comment: i will check this too thx!

Comment: works too!! incredible! I need to know more about lapply again ;D
test = lapply(scan(".txt", what = ' '), function(x) as.logical(as.numeric(strsplit(x, '')[[1]])))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make some sample data:

```
cat("1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0", "0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1", file = "data.txt",
    sep = "\n")
```

Read it in:

```
z <- readLines("data.txt")
```

First we strsplit on spaces:

```
z1 <- lapply(z, function(x) unlist(strsplit(x, " ")))
```

Then we convert to numeric, then logical:

```
lapply(z1, function(x) as.logical(as.numeric(x)))
[[1]]
 [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE

[[2]]
 [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: WOAH! THX! i need to look up lapply - great work!
Need just one more line because of my different input.

z2 <- lapply(z1, function(x) unlist(strsplit(x, "")))